# How can I get my Jpanel Graphics rendering/repainting?

Tags: java, swing

I have a game JPanel that is added to a frame. The gamePanel (posted below) is meant to render movements every frame. public Game() {

```
public Game() {
       Dimension dimension = new Dimension(Game.WIDTH, Game.HEIGHT);
        setPreferredSize(dimension);
        setMaximumSize(dimension);
        setMinimumSize(dimension);
        setVisible(true);

        player = new Player(Game.WIDTH / 2, Game.HEIGHT / 2);
        level = new Level("/map/map.png");
        spriteSheet = new SpriteSheet("/sprites/sprites.png");
        new Texture();
        start();
        setFocusable(true);I cant seem to get the action to happen. 
//other game functions like keybindings.
```

The code that handles the frame rate and what is supposed to paint() to the frame is...

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        requestFocus();// This does not require the mouse to click frame for it to work
        int fps = 0;
        double timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double targetTick = 60.0;
        double delta = 0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / targetTick;

        while (isRunning) {

            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;

            while (delta >= 1) {

                this.tick();
                repaint();//not sure if this is right I just want the frame to update the position of the player and the level
                fps++;
                delta--;

            }
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer >= 1000) {

                fps = 0;
                timer += 1000;
            }
        }
        stop();
    }


    public synchronized void start() {
        System.out.println("start accessed");//this does get accessed

        if (isRunning) return; 
        isRunning = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);//UPDATED
        thread.start();

    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        if (!isRunning) return;
        isRunning = false;
        try {
            thread.join();// what does thread join do?
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void tick() {

        if (enter) { //enter boolean
            System.out.println(enter);
            player.tick();
            level.tick();
            repaint();
            revalidate();

        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, Game.WIDTH, Game.HEIGHT);
        player.render(g);
        level.render(g);

    }
```

essentially the level and the player move over time. I had it working with on a canvas however since then converted the program to use JPanel.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I figured out my issue. In fact it was a thread issue I set the thread target to incorrectly. It should have "this" in parameters.

Comment: Also, do overide paintComponent(Graphics) of the JPanel, not the paint()